Vector Potential and Electric Field
In Yu's Fundamental of Semiconductors, they derive the amplitude of the photon's vector potential (6.32, page 258) when discussing the electron-radiation interactions to be
$$
A=-\frac{E}{2 q}\{\exp [\mathrm{i}(\boldsymbol{q} \cdot \boldsymbol{r}-\omega t)]+\text { c.c. }\},
$$
where $\mathbf{A}$ is $A \mathbf{\hat{e}}$, where $\mathbf{\hat{e}}$ is a unit vector parallel to $\mathbf{A}$ and the incident electric field is $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{q}, \omega)$ and c.c stands for the complex conjugate. Assuming we pick our gauge such that $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A} = 0$ and $\phi = 0 $.
I'm a little confused. Suppose the photon's plane wave is given by $\mathbf{E}(t)=E_0 \exp [i(\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega t)]$. The vector potential is given by $\mathbf{E}=-\frac{\partial \mathbf{A}}{\partial t}$. Integrating givens $- \frac{E_0}{\omega} \exp [i(\mathbf{q} \cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega t)] $, nowhere near the expected value. I don't understand where the complex conjugate comes from either.

In page 260 the conjugate term is explained: it's used so that $A$ is a real function. Remember that $e^{ix}+e^{-ix}=2\cos x$. As for the constant terms that appear in the equation for $A$, I think it may be a mistake, and it should be $E/\omega$. Either that, or the author is implying natural units such that $c=1$, therefore $k=\omega$.

Yu uses cgs units. In cgs units, the electric field is
$$\vec{E} = -\frac{1}{c}\frac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial t}\ , $$ (see eqn. 6.24 in Yu)
and $c =\omega/q$.
If $E = E_0 \sin(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)$, then to a time-independent additive constant, the magnitude of the vector potential is then
\begin{eqnarray}
A & = &-cE_0\int \sin(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)\ dt \\
& = & -\frac{E_0}{q}\cos(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)\\
& = &- \frac{E_0}{2q}\left(\exp[i(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)] + \exp[-i(\vec{q}\cdot \vec{r} - \omega t)]\right)\ .
\end{eqnarray}
